# call phtml file in page builder in magento 2.3 enterprise

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento-enterprise, phtml

I want to call `phtml` file in static block that uses page builder in `Magento 2 EE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  magento2 EE we cant call phtml in block or dynamic block as it uses page builder,we need to create custom content-type follow below tutorial to create custom-content type
[link](https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/create-custom-content-type/step-1-add-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

These steps work for Me:

1. Add Row
2. Add HTML Code element.
3. Call phtml as we do in open source `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::product.phtml"}}` under HTML Code element.
   `